# Помогите разобраться с SAX

Tags: java, xml

Допустим у нас есть XML файл что то там понаписано....
как из него вытащить информацию к примеру только 3 или 4 уровня иерархии?

Answer (score 2):

Вот тебе пример:

xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <library>
    <section>Художественная литература
            <book>
                <title>Жизнь взаймы</title>
                <author>Эрих Мария Ремарк</author>
                <shot_content>Мужчина, его автомобиль, хрупкая девушка, умирающая от туберкулеза.</shot_content>>
            </book>
    </section>
</library>
```

java:

```
public class ParserSAX {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try {
        //Создается фабрика строителей
        SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        //Создается конкретный строитель
        SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        File xmlFile = new File("D:\\library.xml");
        DefaultHandler defaultHandler = new DefaultHandler() {

            boolean bTitle = false;
            boolean bAuthor = false;
            boolean bContent = false;

            //Функция при вызове начального тега
            //uri - пространство имен
            //local name - локальное имя элемента
            //qname - это(local name: uri)
            public void startElement (String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atributess) throws SAXException {

                if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("TITLE")){ bTitle = true; }
                if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("AUTHOR")){ bAuthor = true; }
                if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SHOT_CONTENT")){ bContent = true; }
            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException{
        }

        //Вызывается когда встретился текст
            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException{
                if(bTitle){
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Название книги: " + new String(ch, start, length));
                bTitle = false;
            }
                if(bAuthor){
                System.out.println("Aвтор книги: " + new String(ch, start, length));
                bAuthor = false;
            }
                if(bContent){
                    System.out.println("Cодержание книги: " + new String(ch, start, length));
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                    bContent = false;
                }

        }

        };
        saxParser.parse(xmlFile,defaultHandler);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: а если нам неизвестно имя элементов?

Comment: тогда труднее, SAX событийный парсер, события:обнаружение начального тега и конечного тега, тогда на каждое событие начального тега сохраняешь содержимое тега куда-нибудь.